# Facing RUNTIME error SIGKILL in this code

Tags: c++

Could anyone please tell me why I am facing RUN TIME Error in https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/TEST this CODESHEF question

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a;
    while(true)
    {
        cin>>a;
        if(a!=42)
        cout<<a<<endl;
        else
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to work: [https://ideone.com/rUCBgf](https://ideone.com/rUCBgf)

Comment: It's weird that the first successful solution is this: [https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/37339196](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/37339196) I wonder if the compiler optimized the array out otherwise I would expect a stack overflow as you can't an array of  INT_MAX integers on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The rules:

> rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.

In the example, provided by the contest:

> Input:
> 1
> 2
> 88
> 42
> 99

I did not the contest but I could share my points:

- I guess the program should not end when it receives 42. It should stop processing. Maybe it means you should stop to rewrite numbers. Remove break?
- Numbers should be 1 or 2 digits. Maybe you should test if the input is such a number, then write. So, you should not write "111" for example.

Comment: Thank you for your precious reply . I found that it was because I have to Check the Custom Input table below the question in Codeshef it was weird because it was only for that specific question ,There is nothing like that for other questions . There is no problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check input as integer. If you enter a char this code will loop infintily

Comment: Thank you for your precious reply . I found that it was because I have to Check the Custom Input box below the question in Codeshef it is weird because it is only for that specific question ,There is nothing like that for other questions . There is no problem with the code.